# jQuery - smart hovering plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, hoverintent

Hover events are playing an important role in the navigation of my web page, and I don't want the user to get distracted by triggering them accidentally.

I'm aware of [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html), which doesn't fire a hover event until the mouse has slowed down sufficiently. However, it always fires a hover event when the user scrolls down and lands atop the element.

[Google Images](http://images.google.com) manages to solve this quite beautifully: it doesn't fire hovers when scrolling down, and additionally even jerking the mouse a tiny bit after scrolling into an element doesn't trigger a hover.

Is there any plugin out there that implements hovering behavior similar to Google Images?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this will help: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/

So you will know when the user is scrolling, so you will also know not to fire the hover-event.